# Windows 10 - Customize notification sound based on the keywords in the notification?

Tags: windows-10

Is there any way to alter the sound your notification center makes based on the message text? Example: Outlook notification contains the email's subject line. I would like notification center to make some kind of alarm sound if the notification message contains "Azure Failed Pipeline." I have other use cases in mind outside of Outlook as well.

Comment: I am guessing the Notification Center does not have this level of granularity, but something like AutoHotKey or another system automation app may be able to do this. I recommend checking out that software to see if it can read this email data in Outlook because that'll be the key factor in it being able to do this.